Limit to number of custom search engine shortcuts on Google Chrome Desktop?
I probably have >300 shortcuts accumulated since a decade ago. Recently I noticed it started to act weirdly - old shortcuts which I added are not responding as it should - the shortcut still exists as one of the suggestions, but hitting enter doesn't bring it directly to the URL I wanted it.
So is there a limit and if not, how do I fix this issue?
Also, any way for this feature to be replicated in Chrome Android too? - https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/09/20/i-wish-chromes-custom-search-engines-were-available-on-android/
Thanks!
